# How to write a TensorFlow Lite interpreter that reads input from a CSV file?

Tags: java, python, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When I ran the interpreter code shown below in python I got these results. Basically the model that I have converted into tensorflow lite reads signals as input (csv file).

```
 import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/tmp/arousal_saved_model/arousal_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Print input shape and type
inputs = interpreter.get_input_details()
print('{} input(s):'.format(len(inputs)))
for i in range(0, len(inputs)):
print('{} {}'.format(inputs[i]['shape'], inputs[i]['dtype']))

# Print output shape and type
outputs = interpreter.get_output_details()
print('\n{} output(s):'.format(len(outputs)))
for i in range(0, len(outputs)):
print('{} {}'.format(outputs[i]['shape'], outputs[i]['dtype']))
```

which outputs the following:

```
1 input(s): [ 1 1 14 129] <class 'numpy.float32'> 1 output(s): [1 2] <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

I am new to tensor flow and android, I want to write an interpreter in Android Studio that reads from a csv file input, your help is highly appreciated.